# Grouping the info from two XMLs, where XMLs having common element for mapping

Tags: xslt

Suggest for grouping the info from two XMLs. In my post, based on **employees shift** and **Route number** other information are to be grouped. See the required OutPut for quick review. (XSLT 2)

**Input XML (EmpShift.xml is input to the XSLT):**

```
<MPS>
<emp>
    <name>Rudramuni TP</name>
    <ID>MAC000424</ID>
    <Shift>Second</Shift>
</emp>
<emp>
    <name>Mohan</name>
    <ID>MAC000425</ID>
    <Shift>Second</Shift>
</emp>
<emp>
    <name>Vijay</name>
    <ID>MAC000426</ID>
    <Shift>First</Shift>
</emp>
<emp>
    <name>Shankar</name>
    <ID>MAC000427</ID>
    <Shift>First</Shift>
</emp>
<emp>
    <name>Prasad</name>
    <ID>MAC000428</ID>
    <Shift>Second</Shift>
</emp>
</MPS>
```

**Second Input (Called XML EmpAddressInfo.xml):**

```
<Addess_Info>
<emp>
    <name>Rudramuni TP</name>
    <ID>MAC000424</ID>
    <address>Nandini Layout, B-96</address>
    <Route_No>10</Route_No>
</emp>
<emp>
    <name>Mohan</name>
    <ID>MAC000425</ID>
    <address>Banashankari</address>
    <Route_No>11</Route_No>
</emp>
<emp>
    <name>Vijay</name>
    <ID>MAC000426</ID>
    <address>Marathahalli</address>
    <Route_No>10</Route_No>
</emp>
<emp>
    <name>Shankar</name>
    <ID>MAC000427</ID>
    <address>Yelahanka</address>
    <Route_No>11</Route_No>
</emp>
<emp>
    <name>Prasad</name>
    <ID>MAC000428</ID>
    <address>Marathahalli</address>
    <Route_No>10</Route_No>
</emp>

</Addess_Info>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="varDocAdress" select="document('EmpAddressInfo.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="MPS">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="//emp" group-by="Shift">
          <!--xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="$varDocAdress/Route_No"-->
              <Shift>
                  <Shift-Name><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></Shift-Name>
                  <empDetails><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/name|current-group()/ID"/></empDetails>
              </Shift>
          <!--/xsl:for-each-group-->
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
      <name1><xsl:apply-templates/></name1>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ID">
      <ID><xsl:apply-templates/></ID>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required Result:**

```
<MPS>
<Shift>
   <Shift-Name>Second</Shift-Name>
   <Route_No><title>10</title>
    <empDetails>
       <name1>Rudramuni TP</name1><ID>MAC000424</ID><address>Nandini Layout, B-96</address>
     </empDetails>
     <empDetails>
          <name1>Prasad</name1><ID>MAC000428</ID><address>Marathahalli</address>
        </empDetails>
   </Route_No>

   <Route_No><title>11</title>
        <empDetails>
      <name1>Mohan</name1><ID>MAC000425</ID><address>Banashankari</address>
    </empDetails>
    </Route_No>
</Shift>

<Shift>
   <Shift-Name>First</Shift-Name>
   <Route_No><title>10</title>
   <empDetails>
      <name1>Vijay</name1><ID>MAC000426</ID><address>Marathahalli</address>
   </empDetails>
   </Route_No>

   <Route_No><title>11</title>
       <empDetails>
      <name1>Shankar</name1><ID>MAC000427</ID><address>Yelahanka</address>
   </empDetails>
   </Route_No>
</Shift>
</MPS>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="varDocAdress" select="document('EmpAddressInfo.xml')"/>
<xsl:template match="MPS">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//emp" group-by="Shift">
            <Shift>
                <Shift-Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                </Shift-Name>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="$varDocAdress/Addess_Info/emp[ID = current-group()/ID]" group-by="Route_No">
                    <Route_No>
                    <title><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></title>
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <empDetails>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current()"/>
                            </empDetails>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Route_No>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </Shift>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="emp">
    <name1>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </name1>
    <xsl:copy-of select="ID | address"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Perfect suggestion Lingamurthy. Thanks for the suggestion working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a key for the cross-reference:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="address-url" select="'test2014112603.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="address-doc" select="doc($address-url)"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="emp-by-id" match="emp" use="ID"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MPS">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="emp" group-by="Shift">
      <Shift>
        <Shift-Name><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></Shift-Name>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="key('emp-by-id', ID, $address-doc)/Route_No">
          <Route_No>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></title>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </Route_No>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </Shift>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="emp">
  <empDetails>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name, ID, key('emp-by-id', ID, $address-doc)/address"/>
  </empDetails>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
    <name1><xsl:apply-templates/></name1>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice Key logics, working exactly as required. +1 for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I  would suggest you simplify this by using a **key**:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="varDocAdress" select="document('EmpAddressInfo.xml')"/>
<xsl:key name="emp-by-id" match="emp" use="ID" />

<xsl:template match="/MPS">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="emp" group-by="Shift">
        <Shift>
            <Shift-Name><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></Shift-Name>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="key('emp-by-id', ID, $varDocAdress)/Route_No">
                <Route_No>
                    <title><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></title>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </Route_No>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Shift>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="emp">
    <empDetails>
        <xsl:copy-of select="name | ID | key('emp-by-id', ID, $varDocAdress)/address "/>
    </empDetails>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but some of the information are repeating twice.

Comment: @RudramuniTP I don't see that - which information specifically?

Comment: Sorry its my mistake, your code is working perfectly. Sorry for wrong info, +1 for your suggestion.